# request.url Express and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im a newbie on node.js, I just wanted to know how to extract the requested url in this code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: That code doesn't run in the context of a request, there is no requested URL. Please edit your question to make it more clear what you're really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on the [static middleware source](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js), a middleware is basic a function that receives the parameters `(request, response, next_function)`.

So you could create a function that reads the url before it goes to static middleware.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var staticfn = express.static(__dirname+'/public');
app.use(function (req,res,next) {
    console.log(req.url);
    var sendStream = staticfn(req,res,next);
    console.log(sendStream.path);
});

app.listen(3000)
```

As you can see on the [send package](https://github.com/visionmedia/send/blob/master/lib/send.js) used by the static middleware, the send function returns a object called `SendStream`.